# Pandas - How to merge integer columns into a new integer column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns 'Input_0', 'Input_1' and 'Input_2'. Each contains binary values.

How to combine these to another column which would contain the combined output without turning them into strings, no commas etc. ?

Eg:

```
Input_0 Input_1 Input_2 Input
0       0       1       001
1       1       0       110
1       1       1       111
0       1       0       010
```

I tried to convert into strings but because i intend to do maths on these matrices, since the type is not numerical it doesn't work.

Comment: I do no believe you can have leading zeros without converting it to a string.

Comment: What type are the columns? `int64`? `bool`?

Comment: It's not clear how one generates a string without generating a string. Please clarify your question, if that is a real requirement.

Comment: What kind of operations will you be doing with "Input"? Would it be acceptable to use integers (which do allow for bitwise operations) ?

Comment: At this point, wouldn't it be better to store the binary results and do the maths on them as integers ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io
import pandas as pd

table_str = '''Input_0, Input_1, Input_2
0, 0, 1
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
0, 1, 0
'''

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(table_str), header=0, skipinitialspace=True)
    df['Input'] = df[['Input_0', 'Input_1', 'Input_2']].astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)
    print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
% ./67894205.py
   Input_0  Input_1  Input_2 Input
0        0        0        1   001
1        1        1        0   110
2        1        1        1   111
3        0        1        0   010
```

One can use `print(df.dtypes)` to verify that the original columns remain integers:

```
Input_0     int64
Input_1     int64
Input_2     int64
Input      object
dtype: object
```

If this violates your question parameters, please clarify them.

Another option might be to use `apply` in a column, converting a string literal to a byte literal, or to a bit array via the `bitstring` library, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io
import pandas as pd
import bitstring

table_str = '''Input_0, Input_1, Input_2
0, 0, 1
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
0, 1, 0
'''

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(table_str), header=0, skipinitialspace=True)
    df['Input'] = df[['Input_0', 'Input_1', 'Input_2']].astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)
    df['InputAsByte'] = df['Input'].apply(lambda x: bin(int(x, 2)))
    df['InputAsBitArray'] = df['Input'].apply(lambda x: bitstring.BitArray(bin=x))
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output from this:

```
% ./67894205.modified.py
   Input_0  Input_1  Input_2 Input InputAsByte       InputAsBitArray
0        0        0        1   001         0b1  [False, False, True]
1        1        1        0   110       0b110   [True, True, False]
2        1        1        1   111       0b111    [True, True, True]
3        0        1        0   010        0b10  [False, True, False]
Input_0             int64
Input_1             int64
Input_2             int64
Input              object
InputAsByte        object
InputAsBitArray    object
```

A good answer may depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @user stated that strings were not satisfactory

Comment: Yes, I added a comment asking for clarification, because making a string seems almost certainly a requirement. The first three columns remain integers, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer from @Alex Reynolds and adding a line:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

table_str = '''Input_0, Input_1, Input_2
0, 0, 1
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
0, 1, 0
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(table_str), header=0, skipinitialspace=True)
df['Input'] = df[['Input_0', 'Input_1', 'Input_2']].astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)
df['Input'] = df['Input'].apply(int, args=(2,)).apply(bin) # here you get the data in the column as binary numbers that you can operate
print(df)
```

you get the following output where the column `Input` has binary numbers that you can operate as such:

```
   Input_0  Input_1  Input_2  Input
0        0        0        1    0b1
1        1        1        0  0b110
2        1        1        1  0b111
3        0        1        0   0b10
```